# Title is moving when generating several matplolib images

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to generate several 3d plots using matplotlib. I want to rotate the plot changing the azimuthal angle to generate a .gif. However, when I do so, the title of the graph moves downwards, like so:

Non overlapped title:

[image]

Overlapped title after iteration:

[image]

Here's part of my code:

```py
while it < 50:
    ax.view_init(40, current_angle)
    ax.set_title(r"Graph" %current_angle)
    filename='plot3d%02d'%it + '.png'
    filenames.append(filename)
    plt.savefig(filename)
    it+=1
    current_angle += angle
```

Comment: i recommend putting the title on the figure instead of the `Axes` object. So use `fig.suptitle(...)` instead

Comment: You could also try setting the `y` kwarg of title...